# jqGrid update dropdown options based on first selected dropdown Edit mode

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, jqgrid

I have a jqGrid that loads fine and the drop down loads fine as well but I'm not sure hot to go about updating(loading) the second dropdown based on the first dropdown's onchange event.

Here is my grid. As you can see I load countries but now I would like to load the available currencies based on the selected country.

```
$("#jqgrid").jqGrid
        ({
            url: '@Url.Action("GetSupplierData", "Maintenance")',
            datatype: 'json',
            mtype: 'Get',
            //table header name
            colNames: [
                'Id', 'Code', 'Name', 'Account Number', 'Contact Person', 'Contact Number',
                'Email', 'Address', 'Country', 'Currency', 'InsertUserId',
                'InsertDateTime', 'InsertUserName', 'UpdateUserId', 'UpdateDateTime', 'UpdateUserName'
            ],
            //colModel takes the data from controller and binds to grid
            colModel: [
                {
                    key: true,
                    hidden: true,
                    name: 'id',
                    index: 'id',
                    editable: true
                }, {
                    key: false,
                    name: 'code',
                    index: 'code',
                    editable: true
                }, {
                    key: false,
                    name: 'name',
                    index: 'name',
                    editable: true
                }, {
                    key: false,
                    name: 'accountnumber',
                    index: 'accountnumber',
                    editable: true
                }, {
                    key: false,
                    name: 'contactperson',
                    index: 'contactperson',
                    editable: true
                }, {
                    key: false,
                    name: 'contactnumber',
                    index: 'contactnumber',
                    editable: true
                }, {
                    key: false,
                    name: 'email',
                    index: 'email',
                    editable: true
                }, {
                    key: false,
                    name: 'address',
                    index: 'address',
                    editable: true
                }, {
                    key: false,
                    name: 'countryId',
                    index: 'countryId',
                    editable: true,
                    edittype: 'select',
                    editoptions: {
                        dataInit: function(element) {
                            $.ajax({
                                url: '@Url.Action("GetCountries", "Maintenance")',
                                dataType: 'json',
                                type: 'POST',
                                success: function(response) {
                                    var array = response;
                                    if (array != null) {
                                        var i;
                                        for (i in array) {
                                            if (array.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
                                                if (ctyId == array[i].id) {
                                                    $(element).append("<option value=" + array[i].id +" selected>" + array[i].name +"</option>");
                                                } else {
                                                    $(element).append("<option value=" + array[i].id + ">" + array[i].name + "</option>");
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                        },
                        dataEvents:
                            {
                                type: 'change',
                                fn: function (e) {
                                }
                            }
                    },
                    editrules: { required: true, integer: true }
                }, {
                    key: false,
                    name: 'currencyId',
                    index: 'currencyId',
                    editable: true
                }, {
                    key: false,
                    hidden: true,
                    name: 'insertUserId',
                    index: 'insertUserId',
                    editable: true
                }, {
                    key: false,
                    hidden: true,
                    name: 'insertDateTime',
                    index: 'insertDateTime',
                    editable: true
                }, {
                    key: false,
                    hidden: true,
                    name: 'insertUserName',
                    index: 'insertUserName',
                    editable: true
                }, {
                    key: false,
                    hidden: true,
                    name: 'updateUserId',
                    index: 'updateUserId',
                    editable: true
                }, {
                    key: false,
                    hidden: true,
                    name: 'updateDateTime',
                    index: 'updateDateTime',
                    editable: true
                }, {
                    key: false,
                    hidden: true,
                    name: 'updateUserName',
                    index: 'updateUserName',
                    editable: true
                }
            ],
            rowNum: 10,
            rowList: [10, 20, 30, 40],
            height: '100%',
            caption: 'Suppliers',
            emptyrecords: 'No records to display',
            jsonReader:
            {
                root: "rows",
                page: "page",
                total: "total",
                records: "records",
                repeatitems: false,
                Id: "0"
            },
            pager: '#pjqgrid',
            sortname: 'id',
            toolbarfilter: true,
            viewrecords: true,
            sortorder: "asc",
            autowidth: true,
            multiselect: false,
            onSelectRow: function(id) {
                var selRowId = $("#jqgrid").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow');
                ctyId = $("#jqgrid").jqGrid('getCell', selRowId, 'currencyId');
            }
            //pager-you have to choose here what icons should appear at the bottom
            //like edit,create,delete icons
        }).navGrid('#pjqgrid',
            {
                edit: true,
                add: false,
                del: true,
                search: true,
                refresh: true
            },
            {
                // edit options
                zIndex: 1000,
                url: '@Url.Action("EditSupplier", "Maintenance")',
                dataType: "html",
                closeOnEscape: true,
                closeAfterEdit: true,
                recreateForm: true,
                afterComplete: function(response) {
                    $('#alerts').html(response.responseText);
                }
            },
            {
                // add options

            },
            {
                // delete options
                zIndex: 1000,
                url: '@Url.Action("DeleteSupplier", "Maintenance")',
                type: "POST",
                closeOnEscape: true,
                closeAfterDelete: true,
                recreateForm: true,
                msg: "Are you sure you want to delete this?",
                afterComplete: function(response) {
                    $('#alerts').html(response.responseText);
                }
            });
```

Comment: Id you make your code smaller and have a jsfiddle sample that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

This Guriddo of jqGrid [example](http://www.guriddo.net/demo/guriddojs/edit_add_delete/dialogs_dependent_dropdowns/index.html)  will point you in the right direction.